# How to retrieve AWS S3 objects URL using python

Tags: python

I need to write a lambda function that retrieves s3 object URL for object preview. I came across this solution, but I have a question about it. In my case, I would like to retrieve URL of any object in my s3 bucket, hence there is no Keyname.How can i retriece url of any future objects stored in my s3 bucket.

```
bucket_name = 'aaa'
aws_region = boto3.session.Session().region_name
object_key = 'aaa.png'

s3_url = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.{aws_region}.amazonaws.com/{object_key}"

return {
   'statusCode': 200,
   'body': json.dumps({'s3_url': s3_url})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some examples [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-s3-object-lambda-use-your-code-to-process-data-as-it-is-being-retrieved-from-s3/). But, what exactly would you like to do? What do you mean by future objects? You can put a [creation event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) on your bucket that will trigger your lambda each time when a new object is uploaded into that bucket.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s3.get_object(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=key
    )
    print(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: i would like to be able to retrieve s3 object url for object preview but i dont have KEYNAME